# Debugging EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, exc-bad-access, zombie-process

[image]I've not worked on this project in quite some time.. When I left it some time in the iOS 8s it ran just fine, however.. on the latest XCode I'm getting many inconsistent EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashes. Now afaik it's requiring a deallocated object. However, the error is lacking where to look. This is quite a big project and like I say, the errors are inconsistent.

I've tried enabling zombie objects, as well as passing it as a starting parameter. However, this is leading me to no joy. I'm expecting something in the debug console with zombies enabled, is this right?

If anyone has any tips on how to find an easier way to debug this, as opposed to tinkering with everything and hoping it works..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` just means that your app is trying to access an invalid memory address.   While it is oft caused be a deallocated object, that isn't always the case.

When the app crashes, there should be a crash log or backtrace.  Post it as that'll provide clues.

---

Lovely;  a crash entirely in framework code.   Seeing as how it is SceneKit that is crashing, I would suggest replacing any graphic assets with new ones and see if that fixes it (even if it doesn't look right).   Then check to make sure all of your geometries and layouts are correct.

Comment: Literally no crash log, even if I try to push the breakpoint a little further. I just get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on main, I've tried running the app with allocations instrument with zombies enabled and recording reference counts and when it crashes it provides nothing either.

Comment: added an image upon crash, hopefully that will be better than I can explain.

Comment: well, I've managed to source the issue.. Though there are others. However, the most consistent crash was from removing all children from a spritenode then continuing to redraw them. After removing the remove all children it no longer crashes there. This was found from tinkering as opposed to a direct 'this is wrong' analogy... However, how would have you debugged to find this?

Comment: @daniel by try and error. Remove all the components from the code. Then add them back one after another and try to figure out where and when the crash occurs

Comment: @Daniel That's pretty much what I'd do;  trial and error.   And I would file a bug via bugreporter.apple.com documenting the obtuse failure mode as the team responsible would be interested in improving the experience in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a global Exception or Symbolic breakpoint? Those usually help me 99% of the time when I encounter issues without any sort of backtrace.

Comment: I've tried adding a breakpoint for all 'thrown' exceptions, is this what you're referring to? If so, then this falls into the 1% you mention :(

Comment: That won't work;  an EXC_BAD_ACCESS is a hard crash, not an exception.

Comment: Another option is to type in `bt` in the console after the crash to return a backtrace.